# Добавить время к дате в базу данных

Tags: java, база-данных, swing, jdbc

у меня в базе столбец с типом Timestamp,заношу туда дату как показано на скриншоте,также у меня есть комбобокс,тоже есть на скриншоте,как мне конкатенировать эти две строки чтобы у меня в базе хранилось время и дата ?

[image: Дата]
[image: Комбобокс]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`timestamp` имеет следующий вид: `YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`.
Следовательно:

```java
String time = "11:00"; // из комбо бокса времени
String date = "2021-03-17"; // из комбо бокса даты

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String raw = String.format("%s %s:00", date, time);
TemporalAccessor accessor = formatter.parse(raw);
String timestamp = formatter.format(accessor);
// заносим timestamp в бд
```